# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' in code

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have been getter the error above at random times. One time  the bot passess the point of collectiong 200 k links without the above than at some point it gives the error at 80 k another at 150 k etc. So it is random.

Searching the error i read that it is dues to some threads stuck in something and repeatedly calling itself causing this.

So i went through all my code but i do not see any while or other loops than can be infinite loops other than the main top one to start the threads ?

Here is the main code:First i start the threads :

```
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
               {
                  Console.Write("STARTING THREADS " + j);
                  Thread thread = new Thread(() => startPosting2());
                  thread.IsBackground = true;
                  thread.Start();

                  Random rnd = new Random();
                  int x = 0;
                  x = rnd.Next(1, 10);
                  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * x);
               }
```

Than the scraping :

```
 static int rowCounter = -1;
      int totalRows = 0;
      static  private Object thisLock = new Object();
      public  void startPosting2()
      {
          while (rowCounter < urlList.Count)
          {
              try
              {
                  //List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
                  int tmprowCounter = 0;
                  lock (thisLock)
                  {
                      rowCounter = rowCounter + 1;

                      tmprowCounter = rowCounter;
                  }

                  string url = urlList[tmprowCounter].ToString();
                  scrapsomething(url);

               }
               catch(Exception ex)
               {}
        }
```

The above is the only while loop but it get more link as it goes to total rows can be 100 when it enter the loop and can be 100k and its still in the loop as until it keeps getting links inside it keep adding to the **urlList** . Can this be the cause, And is it bad coding?

**UPDATE**

What if i change the above code to as follows :

```
static int rowCounter = -1;
      int totalRows = 0;
      static  private Object thisLock = new Object();
      public  void startPosting2()
      {
          while (rowCounter < urlList.Count)
          {
              try
              {
                  //List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
                  int tmprowCounter = 0;
                  lock (thisLock)
                  {
                      rowCounter = rowCounter + 1;

                      tmprowCounter = rowCounter;
                  }

                  string url = urlList[tmprowCounter].ToString();
                  Thread t = new Thread(() => scrapeSiteCollectLinks(url));
                  t.Start();
                  t.Join(60000);

               }
               catch(Exception ex)
               {}
        }
```

Will this help ! As if any thing is getting stuck it has to quit after 60 seconds time out ? Is this logic correct?

Comment: System.StackOverflowException is thrown when a function calls itself too many times (recursive). It is not the same as while/for/do loops

Comment: @LostInComputer okz, so some function is calling itself not sure what can that be as i have nothing like that in the code and the worst thing is i cannot debug :| when it occurs i see the error above and no stack trace and clicking continue just closes the bot.

Comment: @LostInComputer My code is simple get url scrape , update labels and listbox and all the process is multithreaded , there is no where a function is calling itself that is what confuses me what should  i look for?

Comment: If you don't have any functions in a loop it is likely a property you have pointing at itself `SomeType Foo { get { return Foo; } }` Got anything like that, perhaps `urlList`?

Comment: Nothing like  SomeType Foo { get { return Foo; } }  but i do have return function in a loop but how can they cause it?Urllist is also added too while scraping and if it gets new links .

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Please see the update and let me know if you are free

Comment: Get the full stack trace of the exception. That will show you the methods that were being called. You should be able to track the error down from there.

Comment: @JimMischel the stack trace is empty :| nothing except one line error above.

Comment: Nothing in the code you show will cause a stack overflow exception. What does your `scrapsomething` method do? Also, your proposed fix won't stop the scraping thread after 60 seconds. Rather, the thread that started the scraping thread will wait for up to 60 seconds, and then continue. But if the scraping thread gets stuck, this won't "unstick" it.

Comment: @JimMischel hi, just realized looking at the EventViewer Log that the app crashes with no error code :| . One before said due to memory over flow. But i was looking at the file running and there was 2.35/4 Ram and cpu usage was approx 10-15 % still it suddenly crashed.
One thing i collect links that get added to selected links, and it reach 250 k into a List  can this be the cause?

Comment: I have no idea where it could be crashing. Just having 250,000 things in a list shouldn't cause a crash, unless you're running out of memory. There simply isn't enough information here to diagnose the problem. If you have no error message and no idea where in your code it might be crashing, and no diagnostic information to share, all we can do is guess ... and not very intelligently. You need to spend some time narrowing down the cause. That might involve logging, running it in the debugger, or other diagnostic techniques. We can't do that for you.